# JQuery error option in $.ajax utility

Tags: jquery, ajax

The documentation indicates that the error: option function will make available: XHR instance, a status message string (in this case always error) and an optional exception object returned from the XHR instance (Book: JQuery in Action)

Using the following (in the $.ajax call) I was able to determine I had a "parsererror" and a "timeout" (since I added the timeout: option) error

```
error: function(request, error){}
```

What are other things you evaluate in the error option? do you include the optional exception object?

**EDIT:** one of the answers indicates all the return errors...learning more about what is of value (for debugging) in the XHR instance and exception object would be helpful

This is a complete $.ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: "http://myServer/cgi-bin/broker" ,
 dataType: "text",
 data: {
 '_service' : 'myService',
 '_program' : 'myProgram',
 'start' : start,
 'end' : end
 },
 beforeSend: function() {
  $("#loading").removeClass("hide");
 },
 timeout: 5000,
 error: function(request,error) {
  $("#loading").addClass("hide");
  if (error == "timeout") {
   $("#error").append("The request timed out, please resubmit");
  }
  else {
   $("#error").append("ERROR: " + error);
  }
  },
  success: function(request) {
   $("#loading").addClass("hide");
   var t = eval( "(" + request + ")" ) ;
  } // End success
}); // End ajax method
```

Thanks for the input

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery source code, there are four returned statuses, in additon to **success**:

- **timeout** - when your specified
  timeout is exceeded
- **error** - http error, like 404
- **notmodified** - when requested
  resource was not modified since last
  request
- **parsererror** - when an xml/json response is
  bad

Comment: also when dataType: "json" and the json is incorrectly formed

Answer (score 43):

I find the request more useful than the error.

```
error:function(xhr,err){
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
```

**xhr** is XmlHttpRequest.
**readyState** values are 1:loading, 2:loaded, 3:interactive, *4:complete*.
**status** is the HTTP status number, i.e. 404: not found, 500: server error, *200: ok*.
**responseText** is the response from the server - this could be text or JSON from the web service, or HTML from the web server.

Answer (score 4):

This is an aside, but I think there's a bug in the code you submitted. The line:

```
 if (error = "timeout") {
```

should have more equals signs in it:

```
 if (error == "timeout") {
```

Comment: good catch, edited the post. It has been a while since I posted this, but I think that was just a typo. thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

The second argument that is passed to your error function will either be the string "timeout" "parserror" "error" or "notmodified". The third will be the exception object. This object can be helpful for debugging.

Comment: could you update your answer to explain the helpful debug info that can be obtained from the exception object

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that response is correct? Parse error mean that there is sth wrong with data being evaluted in line
`var t = eval( "(" + request + ")" ) ;`

Comment: sorry, my question wasn't clear. I worked through my "parsererror" problems...I was wondering what other info can be determined from the error: option