# Why does this not work on blackberry

Tags: jquery, ajax, blackberry, jquery-mobile

I have an ajax function that works on Android, iPhone, Blackberry torch and webkit browsers. Im trying to test this on various version 5 and 6 blackberry simulators but the error handler always gets called.

eg response in message boxes is: Error, Complete.

The error returned from the function is: 
'Error- Status: error jqXHR Status: 0 ResponseText:'

Whereas all other devices is: Success Complete.

Do I have to do something special for blackberry?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        //Login form Login link click
        $("#login a.login").click(function () {

            //Call the approve method on the code behind
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Login.aspx/LoginUser",
                data: "{'Username':'admin', 'Password':'admin' }", //Pass the parameter names and values
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Error- Status: " + textStatus + " jqXHR Status: " + jqXHR.status + " jqXHR Response Text:" + jqXHR.responseText) },
                success: function () { alert('success'); window.location.href = "Index.aspx"; },
                complete: function () { alert('complete'); }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try editing your error function to be [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95600/jquery-error-option-in-ajax-utility/1956505#1956505) and see if that provides more useful information. Post back what it tells you.

Comment: @Core.B - I did have an error handler like that before but i removed it for simplicity. Please see edit to original question to show updated code and error message returned

Comment: Can you browse any external websites from the simulator? Can you go to your Login.aspx page in the browser? I assume you're using the full url w/ "http://" in the front. The only reason I know for getting error status 0 is that the browser can't reach the external site.

Comment: @Core.B - I just tested with external sites and they are working ok, I too can browse to the site running on my local IIS from withing the BB emulator. Have you ever got any ajax working on Blackberry simulators in the past? Im sure its just blackberry being rubbish as it works on all other phones, just rather not have to have a seperate set of pages with no ajax for BB's

Comment: I've never tried to do this, but try one last test building the XMLHTTPRequest object yourself and doing the call to test if Blackberry or JQuery is giving the problem.

Comment: @Core.B - I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by Building the XMLHttp Request object yourself. How wouldd I Go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never got to the bottom of this, only solution is to not use ajax for version 4 and 6 BB's

Comment: blackberry and RIM need to be shutdown. Absolute crap code and development.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a copy and paste from your code, try changing "ssuccess" to "success" and see if that corrects it.

Comment: I have corrected the spelling mistake in the code, not sure how it got in there as its not in my project code so unfortunately that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your url in the whitelist

```
<access uri="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />
```

or

```
<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
```