# AJAX Login form, update page content after logging in

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Imagine that I have a page, with a login/logout function in the header, which works fully via AJAX.

If a user isn't logged in, I want to show him "Hey, login" and allow him to login via ajax. That's all good, and it works.

But if the user logs in, I can't access anything that DIDN'T get put on the page -- the content that is there when the user accesses the page when they are successfully logged in.

If I view the page source, elements are there, but if I do things such as `$("#container").show()`, `.slideDown()`, `.html()`, none of them are doing anything.

Do I have to make the user refresh the page, or store all of the code in javascript to deploy? I hope not.

I've included my Javascript for the login below, but that's not really the point. That's working. Where I say `$("#all").slideDown()` is the problem. Even when accessing it through the console, it won't do anything.

The problem is probably related to dying with PHP if the user isn't logged in. This code is executed in  `$(function() { }`

Code:

```
/* Get the AJAX Login form Ready */
$("#login-form").submit(function() { 
    $("#login-error").hide();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (username == "" || password == "") {
        $("#login-error").show();
        $("#login-error-heading").html("You've entered something wrong.");
        $("#login-error-content").html("Please enter both a username and a password.");
        return false;
    }
    $.get( 
        "process-login.php",
        {
            username:username,
            password : password
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.success == 1) {
                /* Hide the login form */
                $("#login").modal("hide");

                /* remove the login button */
                $('#nav-login').remove();

                /* add the logout button to the DOM */
                $("#nav-container").append('<ul id="user-options" class="nav pull-right"><li class="divider-vertical"></li><li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Logged in as ' + data.username + '<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="javascript:logout();">Logout</a></li></ul></li></ul>');

                $("#all").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#login-error").show();
                $("#login-error-heading").html("You've entered something wrong.");
                if (data.success == 3) {
                    $("#login-error-content").html("This account is locked out because of incorrect password usage. Please try again in 10 minutes.");
                } else {
                    $("#login-error-content").html("The username and password combination was not found.");
                }
            }
        }, 
        "json"
    );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You need to include the javascript/jquery as the page is loaded. running an ajax call will log you into the site but may require a refresh if you are attempting to use code that is only available when logged in. basically if your going to use it, it needs loading.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the html that is delivered with this on page load.

Comment: Is `.modal('hide')` the right way to hide dialog panels? Are you using jqueryui or another plugin for the dialog?

Comment: If it's resolved, it would be great to know what fixed it. Post it as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think it's a good idea to use AJAX to divide your presentation logic.  I'd use PHP to detect whether they're logged in first, and separate the views accordingly.

If you must use AJAX to do this, I'd suggest redirecting because that's what I like when I log in.  It feels like a fresh start. If you don't want to redirect, why don't you put all of the layout changes in a separate function like:

```
function openSesame() {
   $('div.welcome_page').slideUp();
   $('div.treasure_trove').show();
}
```

And call it in your AJAX's `success` setting.

Comment: Not really using AJAX to divide it. Basically, I am checking in the content with PHP if the user is logged in. If not, I die with an error saying to login. That works fine. But once I log out, I can't really display anything else.

Comment: @MichaelHogue : I have to agree with Jamie. You shouldn't use ajax for loading content after login, especially if the page is basically blank before logging in. That gives me the creeps as though the content was always there hiding.  I do like how sites like hulu do the asynch log in, but in all the examples I can think of like that, the only difference after log in is extended visibility, seeing links to protected info, not the full page.

Comment: I can't really detect the problem without any example code. As to async logins, they creep me out as well. I've worked with AJAX for so long I'm just _waiting_ for something to crash. It's like a Pavlovian tic

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a javascript error on your page. I'm assuming your logged in section is being served over HTTPS. If that's the case, and if your javascript functionality is stored in a .js file, then you might need to include your javascript file over https as well.

Using a network path reference (or protocol agnostic path) helps resolve these kinds of https vs http issues.

```
<script src="\\js\myJsFile.js"></script>
```

*Edit:*

You might try the $.ajax function so that you can catch any errors that do occur... This might tell you more about what is actually happening with your request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "process-login.php",
    data: {
        username: username,
        password: password
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // your function
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, error) { // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1956505/296889
        alert("readyState: " + jqXhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + jqXhr.status);
        alert("Response Received: " + jqXhr.responseText);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but no HTTPS is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, we can't do much. I would check to make sure that you aren't attempting to use a bound event on something that didn't exist at the time of the initial bind. If something doesn't exist until your AJAX callback, then you'll have to bind it after it's been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe the issue is that your new content, while in the DOM isn't bound to any of the jquery event handlers.  The way to bind events to future elements is to use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, like so:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I didn't add the new content. It's there in the page source. I think it's related to dying in PHP. Probably what is happening.

Comment: So the content is already loaded on the page and is just hidden? What is to prevent someone from just viewing the source before login or passing in a "true" value to the ajax callback function? More to your problem, does the content show up at all after success? How do you know they are logging in? Probably we'll need to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

As @jamie said, don't mix JS and business logic if you don't have to.

This is where you need to use a templating engine, and make an attempt at building something that resembles MVC. Check out Smarty http://www.smarty.net/, or if you really want a legit MVC framework you can go with CakePHP or Symfony.

You do not need to redirect. It's slow and not exactly enjoyable for the user.

Let's just take a pseudo-code example using Smarty:

```
global $smarty;

//go grab your user object
$user = PseudoUser::validate_current_user();
if( $user->login_status === true )
{
  //user is logged in
  $smarty->assign( 'user', $user );
  $smarty->display( 'logged_in_template.tpl' );
}
else
{
  //user is logged out
  $smarty->display( 'logged_out_template.tpl' );
}
```

Bada bing bada boom.

With the js ajax login, yes, you should just refresh the page in this case. Your PHP controller should have already established what to do when the page is reloaded.