# How to display error returned by $.ajax call?

Tags: jquery

I have a code that takes forever to load, and finally when I put error handler it shows alert, but I need to know what error it returned? How can I know?

**EDIT: I get requested url not found, but I am certain the url: is a valid URL on my host, what could be wrong? I can even access it directly in browser.**

```
// process logging in a user from sidebar
$("#login-form").submit(function(event) {
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
    $("p.form-result").empty();
    $('p.form-submit').after('<p class="loading"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/loading.gif" alt="" /></p>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax/login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('.loading').remove();
            $('input:submit').attr("disabled", false);
            if (data.status) {
                // success
                $("p.form-result").html('<span class="success">' + data.message + '</span>');
                window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000);
            } else {
                // error
                $("p.form-result").html('<span class="error">' + data.message + '</span>');
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` instead of `alert('error')`?

Comment: have you tried inspecting that `data` variable within your `error` function?

Comment: `alert(data.message);` (If data.message contains something useful)

Comment: I tried an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676084/how-do-i-return-a-proper-success-error-message-for-jquery-ajax-using-php and it returned Requested url not found.

Answer (score 20):

The `error` event of the jQuery function `$.ajax` receives 3 arguments

```
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

}
```

This is the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this event :

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
>   of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an
>   Ajax Event.

You'll we be able to know what error is with the parameter `textStatus`

Answer (score 9):

Error event in ajax call get executed when ajax call has some invalid arguments in it. Following function will help you to understand error code by throwing an error and displaying error definition in alert.

```
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                },
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the data parameter of your error function to alert the error and its properties. It mimics your actual error.

```
error: function(data){
     alert(data);
}
```

Possible values for the data (error) object according to this question's ([JQuery error option in $.ajax utility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95600/jquery-error-option-in-ajax-utility)) answer

```
timeout - when your specified timeout is exceeded
error - http error, like 404
notmodified - when requested resource was not modified since last request
parsererror - when an xml/json response is bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax/login.php',
```

By this

```
url: '<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/ajax/login.php',
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check object data by using alert statement

use console.log(data) to check the error

```
error: function(data){
     console.log(data);
}
```