# jQuery ajax load method stucked in loading

Tags: ajax, jquery

I've searched all over the site but I couldn't find anything that helped me, so here it is:

I have this html file that when you click on Get extern it should place the content from extern.html into the div named content, but is getting stucked, when you click on the link it shows loading and that's it.

[image]

test.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  // select all the links with class="lnk", when one of them is clicked, get its "href" value
  // adds a "loading..." notification, load the content from that URL and
  // place only the paragraph which is in the #cnt into the tag with id="content"
  $('a.lnk').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ ' #cnt p');
    return false;
  });
});
--></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Web page test.html</h1>
<a href="extern.html" title="Get extern" class="lnk">Get extern</a>
<div id="content">Initial content in test.html</div>
```

extern.html file

```
<h2>Content in extern.html</h2>
<div id="cnt"><p>Some text content in extern.html</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your trying to load an external webpage, but it's getting blocked by the same origin policy in your browser. If not, there's a quick way to debug this.

1) My favorite is to use the Chrome developer panel (open by pressing F12). Go to the network tab and try to load the external page via your jQuery. Then you can watch the network activity and see if any errors come up.

2) User $.ajax instead of $.load. See here for more options: [JQuery error option in $.ajax utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95600/jquery-error-option-in-ajax-utility)

If the problem is indeed the same domain policy look into jQuery's JSONP functionality. One example is here: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since the href has a relative url it wouldn't be SOP.

Comment: @Musa Indeed. I didn't notice the first time I read it... It doesn't really affect the two suggestions though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally this **'Loading'** appears when the script is not successfully executed or some logical/syntax error is occured. I assume you verified your script with firebug, I suggest you to check with **$.noConfllict();** in case  if your page has multiple script blocks and libraries conflicting each other.